# Disable redirect in fetch request using React native

Tags: redirect, react-native, fetch

I'm trying to crawl a web using React Native which has no API. It's written in PHP.

To log an user, a POST request must be sent. The response returns a cookie with a PHPSessid cookie which I must capture to use in subsequent requests.

I would like to capture the cookie value, buy the POST response is a 302 and the redirection is followed automatically, so I can't see the cookie. In node I was able to do it with `redirect:manual`, but it does not work in react native.

The cookie is sent automatically in subsequent requests, buy I'm trying to manage cookies by hand with react-native-cookie and I'd like to know if it's possible.

Do you know a way to stop the redirection?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Alvaro - did you find a solution?

Comment: I just posted what I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been checking the code and what I did was the following:

- Clear all cookies
- Launch an empty login request
- Capture the PHPSessID coookie
- Launch a login request with that PHPSessID
- After that, the subsequent fetch requests would have automatically a PHPSessID cookie with a valid logged in user, so we can use the site with simple fetchs

Here is some code, but the important thing is that you do a first empty login request, capture the PHPSessid and launch the real login request with that PHPSessid.

This would be the main function:

```js
import Cookie from 'react-native-cookie';
  // I think this is used only to clear the cookies

function login(user, pass){

    // clear all cookies for all domains
    // We need to start withouth authorization token
    Cookie.clear();

    const makeLoginRequest = (sessid) => 
             makeLoginRequestForUserAndPass(user,pass,sessid);

    return makeInitialRequest()
        .then(getSessionIDFromResponse)
        .then(makeLoginRequest)
        .then(checkIfLoggedAndGetSessionID);
}
```

The initial request is a request to the login script. Note that I used GET because it worked with my site, perhaps an empty post would be necessary:

```js
function makeInitialRequest() {
    const INIT_PATH = '/index.php?r=site/login';
    const INIT_URL = site + INIT_PATH;
    const request = new Request(INIT_URL, options....);

    return fetch(request);
}
```

We have the session ID in the response. I used a simple regex to extract it. Note that we are not logged in; PHP has created a session and that's what we have here:

```js
function getSessionIDFromResponse(response) {
    return getPHPSessIdFromCookie(response.headers.get('set-cookie'));
}

function getPHPSessIdFromCookie(header) {
    const regex = /PHPSESSID=(\w*)/;
    const match = regex.exec(header);
    return match ? match[1] : '';
}
```

Now the login request. Note that I can't stop redirection here, but I't have to do it because we can have PHPSessid later. Redirection must be set to manual in POST request:

```js
function makeLoginRequestForUserAndPass(user, pass, sessid) {
    const request = buildLoginRequest(user, pass, sessid);
    return fetch(request);
}

// This is where we build the real login request
function buildLoginRequest(user, pass, sessid) {
    const LOGIN_PATH = '/index.php?r=site/login';
    const LOGIN_URL = site + LOGIN_PATH;

    const fields = [
        {name: 'LoginForm[username]', value: user},
        {name: 'LoginForm[password]', value: pass},
        etc...
    ];
    const data = translateFieldsToURLEncodedData(fields);

    const headers = {
        'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        Cookie: `PHPSESSID=${sessid}`, // HERE is where you put the data
    };

    const options = { method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        mode: 'cors',
        cache: 'default',
        agent: proxy,
        body: data,
        redirect: 'manual'  // VERY IMPORTANT: if you don't do it, the cookie is lost
    };

    return new Request(LOGIN_URL, options);
}

// Simple utility function
function translateFieldsToURLEncodedData(fields){
    let pairs = fields.map( (field) => {
        return encodeURIComponent(field.name) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(field.value);
    });
    return pairs.join('&');
}
```

This is the last part. To see if I was logged in I checked if the response had text belonging to login error's page. I also got the PHPSessid (I think it changed after login, not sure, it was a year ago) but I don't know if I used it, I believe it was included automatically in subsequent requests. I think this part could be simplified an improved:

```js
function checkIfLoggedAndGetSessionID(response) {
    return (
        checkIfLoggedOK(response)
            .then(() => getSessionIDFromResponse(response))
    );
}

function checkIfLoggedOK(response){
    return getTextFromResponse(response)
        .then(throwErrorIfNotLogedOk);
}

function getTextFromResponse(response) {
    return response.text();
}

function throwErrorIfNotLogedOk(page) {
    if(isErrorPage(page)) throw new Error("Login failed");
}

function isErrorPage(text) {
    const ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Something that appears in login failed page of your site';
    let n = text.search(ERROR_MESSAGE);
    return n !== -1;
}
```

Hope this can be useful.